# How to get ReceiveResult value on a different activity?

Tags: android

I'm developing something like an internet speed meter app. Which tells about upload and download rate. I am using a service for that.

Let's say I start service from Activity A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service.class);
intent.putExtra("receiver", new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            int d = resultData.getInt("progress");
        }
    }
});
startService(intent);
```

Service class gave me the value of the `d` variable.

Is it possible to directly get that value in activity B which is not even started yet, but whenever users start that Activity, they get to see the value of `ResultReceiver`?

Answer (score 0):

Use callback pattern for callback data from service to activity,You can pass this callback instance to another activity

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `public static` variable, let's name it `theLastTestedSpeed`, and assign the value to it. Then you can access it in any `activity` you want.

---

**Updated**

Give you a simple example that may fit your needs.

`Service`:

```
public class SpeedMeterService extends Service {

    private static SpeedResultListenerGroup listenerGroup = new SpeedResultListenerGroup();


    public interface SpeedResultListener {
        void onUpdate(int resultInTestingProgress);

        void onFinalResult(int finalResult);
    }

    private static class SpeedResultListenerGroup implements SpeedResultListener {
        private List<SpeedResultListener> resultListeners = new ArrayList<>();

        public void register(SpeedResultListener listener) {
            resultListeners.add(listener);
        }

        public void unregister(SpeedResultListener listener) {
            resultListeners.remove(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(int resultInTestingProgress) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinalResult(int finalResult) {

        }
    }

    public static void register(SpeedResultListener listener) {
        listenerGroup.register(listener);
    }

    public static void unregister(SpeedResultListener listener) {
        listenerGroup.unregister(listener);
    }

    private void yourSpeedTestFunctionHere() {
        //every time you got speed updated during tesing progress, call: listenerGroup.onUpdate(updatedSpeed);
        //when you got the final speed, call: listenerGroup.onFinalResult(finalTestedSpeed);
    }

}
```

`Activity`:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    private SpeedMeterService.SpeedResultListener listener = new SpeedMeterService.SpeedResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(int resultInTestingProgress) {
            // TODO: 12/3/20 doUpdatedStuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinalResult(int finalResult) {
            // TODO: 12/3/20 doFinalSpeedFetchedStuff

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SpeedMeterService.register(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        SpeedMeterService.unregister(listener);
    }
}
```

Now in `activity B` you can simply call `SpeedMeterService.register(callback)` to get the updated result.

Comment: That's only gave one time value. It's not going to get updated.